# Check for NULL or empty variable (MySQL stored procedure)

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone indicate the proper syntax to determine whether a variable is `NULL` or empty and then take appropriate action to set the variable depending on the result.

I currently have a test for `NULL` which works fine (part of a MySQL `SELECT` statement / stored procedure).

```
IFNULL(@previousTs, '2017-00-04 00:00:01') ts
```

I want to include (in the same single line) a test for empty (`NULL` or empty both results in `@previousTs` being set to `2017-00-04 00:00:01`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
IF(@previousTs IS NULL or @previousTs= '', '2017-00-04 00:00:01', @previousTs )
```